# Null reference exception error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, view

I have a Student data model(Entity Framework) where I have set both "StudentID" and "StudentName" as primary keys. StudentID is of type Int and StudentName is of type String.

I created a strongly-typed view, But when I run it i get the following error:

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

> ```
> Source Error: 
>
>
> Line 10:         <tr>
> Line 11:             <td>
> Line 12:                 <%= Html.Encode(item.StudentID) %>**
> Line 13:             </td>
> Line 14:             <td>
> ```

Here is my controller action:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        ViewData.Model = student.StudentTable;
        return View();
    }
```

Here is the View:

```
    <%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Student.Models.StudentTable>>" %>

<html>
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <table>

    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.StudentID) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.StudentName) %>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <% } %>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show the code from your Controller Action method?

Comment: @frennky I added my view above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any additional information, my guess is that `item` is `null`. If the Student Table has a SINGLE StudentID per record, then you need to simply pass `model.StudentID`

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{    
    var model = student.StudentTable;
    return View(model);
}
```

aspx

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.StudentID) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.StudentName) %>
        </td>
    </tr>

<% } %>
```

Comment: I still get the same error, I added my controller and view above

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `ViewData.Model = student.StudentTable;` and check to see if `StudentID` is `null` in any of your records. Also, I recommend passing the model to the view instead of using the ViewData... `return View(model);`

Comment: Yes, there are couple null values for StudentID, which I have set as identity key. How do I overcome that? Also when passing the model in view like: <%= Html.Encode(model.StudentID) %> How would it get all the students in StudentTable, wouldn't I need a for loop for that?

Comment: your loop is fine, your problem is with the `null` values in `StudentID`. If they are supposed to have a value, then I would recommend setting a value. It sounds to me like the Database is not properly setting the ID. Do you have it set to Auto Increment, or are you relying on your application to set the ID?

Comment: Database does not set that value, it is actually StudentID like "JSmith114", Hence I have StudentID and StudentName as Primary key. How can I set a value for nulls?

Comment: You can create a primary key by selecting two of your rows in Sql Management Studio, right clicking and setting it as a primary key. Then it will throw an error if your software tries to insert a null value into either of the two fields. HOWEVER, you're better off to have a single primary key with either an int or a uniqueidentifier.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt item is null, if it were null you wouldn't get inside the loop. Set a break point and examine item, it's probably not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the line you're getting the exception on, then your `item` variable must be null. You'll need to look closely at how that's being populated - if your model is null, then you should be able to throw a debugger on your controller action and figure out why that's not working.

Comment: Yes, That is the line. It works for other actions where I pass parameters

Answer (score 0):

Could be a few things ...

Are you passing up valid view data from the ActionMethod? 
Have you defined @model on the view?

Assuming student.StudentTable is a single object with StudentID property then you need to change your view code to Model.StudentID